# What is the ` key on a Mac French (Canada) keyboard?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I was a bit annoyed that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, in Mac OS, cycled between applications, not windows, on Macs, and I was looking for a way to do this with windows instead. For example, if I have 2 Finder windows and one Firefox window, a shortcut that would bring me from the first to the second Finder window instead of Firefox.

I think I found something like this in the Finder's application menu. Well, when I clicked it, at the first glance, I think it did more or less that. The shortcut mentioned was <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. I can find the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key all right, but what the heck is <kbd>`</kbd>? I'm pretty sure I've tried the whole keyboard.

EDIT: The Macs I have tried this with are running Snow Leopard in French (Canada), and their keyboard configuration is very much akin to the Canadian multilingual standard one that I use on my PC, except for the fact that "complicated" characters are performed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+*<kbd>key</kbd>* instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*Key*</kbd>/<kbd>AltCar</kbd>+<kbd>*Key*</kbd>, as it is on Windows.

Comment: out of curiosity, how are you writing that if you don't know where it is? :D

Comment: @ataulm: I'm 1. on a Windows computer; 2. using Ctrl+alt+[the key on the right of the P] on my keyboard. My keyboard layout is Canadian multilingual standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your keyboard layout in *System Preferences » Language & Text » Input Sources*, where you can also activate the *Keyboard Viewer* shown below.

- With the *Canadian French (CSA)* layout, the *back tick* key is to the left of *Return* while you hold the *Option* key (not the "highlighted" one — it's a *dead key* —, the one to its lower right).

  [image: Screenshot of Keyboard Viewer]
- With the *Canadian English* layout, it's to the right of the left *Shift* key, without modifiers.
- For other layouts, enable *Keyboard Viewer* in the *Input Sources* screen of *System Preferences*, then open it via the the *Input Sources* menu bar item on the right, and try a combination of *Opt*, *Ctrl*, and *Shift* to find the *back tick* key.

Note that in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, you can change the keyboard shortcut for the window switching command.

Comment: http://notavailablein.ca/2011/03/death-to-the-canadian-multilingual-bilingual-keyboard/

Comment: that keyboard looks like it's for opening portals to stargates.

Comment: @Sirex Any OS X keyboard layout looks like then when you're holding down *Option*.

Comment: is one of the options opening a portal to a stargate ?

Comment: Uhm, so the final keyboard shortcut is Cmd+Alt+^? 1. Why the heck doesn't it display that instead, if that's the case? 2. I think I remember trying that too. 3. "Option" is Alt, right?

Comment: @ataulm: Lol. I hate keyboards with a "short and wide" Enter key. Those are the evil ones. Most of the time, they even lack the key for French quotes next to left shift key, too! D:

Comment: @Ariane No, *Command-Option-à* if that's the correct layout. *Cmd-`* is the shortcut independent of keyboard layout (most layouts are much saner, that's why I explain how to simply change it)

Comment: Independent of keyboard, meaning it actually is the key next to 1, according to you? And uhm, I'm guilty of having half-heartedly read your answer. Sorry. But as for changing shortcuts, it's so-so, since the Macs at school are Deep Frozen.

Comment: @Ariane No, it means it's always *Cmd-`* no matter what your layout. While *Cmd-Opt-à* would be easier to find for you, it would change the actual key combination of the shortcut for all other keyboard layouts. Custom keyboard shortcuts are a personal preference per user account (similar to wallpaper, screensaver, etc.), unless they mess with that, it should work.

Comment: Well, we don't have user accounts on the computers. Only on the network, for files. (That thing you log in to with Cmd+K.)

Comment: On Windows I press AltGr+^ for this key. I must then also press SPACE to get the ` character. This is because the ` key is also an accent key, used to make accented characters such as ò and ì which are not already on the CSA keyboard but are needed for typing in some international languages.

Answer (score 2):

It's next to the "1" key, on the left.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Heh. On my keyboard as well as those at school (Canadian multilingual standard), this key displays | # \ or | / \, depending on whether the keyboard is printer for Canadian multilingual standard or French (Canada). Though the Mac being configured in French as well, I sort of doubt it would point to -that- key. @Kruug read this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key with your <kbd>é</kbd> key.

[Mac Keyboard Layout http://emsjuwel.com/learn.quebec.french/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Canadian_French_Multilingual_Keyboard-600x461.png](http://emsjuwel.com/learn.quebec.french/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Canadian_French_Multilingual_Keyboard-600x461.png)

Comment: I don't even have the said Mac to test it (the only Macs I use are those at school, and not by choice), but since I pretty much mashed every key, or so I believe, let's assume it's not this, that I've just tried it and it's not the right key. What can it be? (Gonna add a few possibly useful details to the question in a second.)

Comment: @Ariane See edited post.

Comment: Alt Gr + É does nothing on my present keyboard. But then again, contrary to that image, AltGr + È does not do anything. Nor does it do a "micro" symbol upon pressing it with M. Looks like you have the wrong layout.